# boto.sns BotoServerError when publishing a notification

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sns

I am using Python 2.7 and boto library for Amazon SNS. I am trying to send a notification when I get an exception with detail of the exception. In some cases exception string contains strings like this "`--->`" or " `\` ". I suspect these characters causing `BotoServerError` as a Bad Request.

Full exception string:

```
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request None
```

What is the best way of preventing my application from this exception?

Edit: Here is the code that I am sending message:

```
sns = boto.sns.connect_to_region(credentials...)
sns.publish(topicArn, message, subject)
```

This is message:

```
Type: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
Detail: ('invalid literal for int() with base 10: \'{"default":"216","sqs":"216"}\'',)
```

Comment: Could you post your code somewhere?

Comment: @garnaat thanks for your attention. I've just edited question to include code sample..

Comment: The first parameter boto.sns.connect_to_region should be a region_name.  Is that just a cut/paste error?  Or are you forgetting the region_name in the call?

Comment: @garnaat No no I just wanted to refer my credentials not to write all of them here.. My module is working fine in most messages. But sometimes if there are some specials chars I get an exception.